# Porting POST from u-boot to linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, u-boot

U-boot on my platform provides POST(Power on self test) for UART and DDR .Now for some requirement I need to port it to Linux.

I need to know, is it possible porting POST from u-boot to Linux , will it work?

Also, is there some other ways to do self post for UART and DDR at kernel level?

Thanks
Amit.

Comment: Everything is possible in virtual world.

Comment: *"is it possible porting POST from u-boot to Linux"* -- Possible: maybe. Practical: no.  Linux enables the MMU and the data cache rather early in the kernel startup code.  You would want to perform the DDR tests before that happens.  U-Boot is the far more sensible program to do that.  What is the perceived benefit of this (IMO misguided) requirement?

Comment: Ok ,I understand that kernel is cache able but I failed to understand how it impact DDR self tests at kernel level,would you please tell me why it is good to have POST at u-boot level itself ?

Comment: I already answered one of your questions.  It's your turn to answer my question.

Comment: Sorry @sawdust, I really didn't come up with detailed requirement(as I'm not sure about this POST ) but what I'm looking for is, if any of the mentioned Devices goes down in production environment it somehow should be reported by some medium,Would you like to point out to some good approaches for the same?

Comment: *"if any of the mentioned Devices goes down in production environment it somehow should be reported by some medium"* -- That should be handled by the device drivers or application programs using the devices when those issues occur (e.g. proper error detection and logging).  "Testing" devices while they're in use is rarely practical or effective.  And such *"testing"* or monitoring would have nothing to do with *" power on"* or POST.